# Show comments in Backend

Tags: wp-admin, comments

On my website I implemented, that every user can comment on every image on the site. So it is possible to comment every image in a blogpost for example. Everything works fine and I can display them on the frontend.

My question is, how can I display them in the backend? I can access them in the database like the comments written in the normal commentform.

I hope I could clearly explain what I want.
If not, ask me please.
Thanks!

Comment: How did you implement that?

Comment: Long story short: the input (mail, name, message) is inserted via mysql in the db

Comment: But in a seperate table and not in wp_comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my question coincidentally in the comments section. Just put your self made comments in the right table: wp_comments and everything works like a charm... :)